# I have a Lubuntu 14 / Windows Vista Dual boot and I need to upgrade Lubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, updates, lubuntu, touchscreen

Could you please tell me how to go about updating Lubuntu?
I am on a dual boot with W Vista
The hardware is a HP Smart Touch all in one, the touchscreen is working perfectly in Lubuntu.
I am pretty much unable to download or update any apps anymore so I need to update Lubuntu. After 8 years I guess it is about time.
I really would like to install Zoom.
Could you please advise on the best way to do this?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is an 8 year old version you want update it would be best to install the new version not try to update. Are you sure your hardware can run the current version? You also should be clear on what version you are running as there is no version 14

Comment: And while installing from scratch a supported release/version, also delete Vista.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/  FYI: Lubuntu 14.04 being a *flavor* reached EOL in 2017; 3 years after release.

Comment: Lubuntu has switched desktops as well; Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last using LXDE and it's now EOL. All later releases required re-install, eg. read the 20.04 release notes https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/ (*before 18.04 reached EOL; the notice was removed once 18.04 reached EOL in April 2021*)  "**Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.**"

Comment: @guiverc great point! Added that to the answer. If you have any suggestions the make it clearer, please feel free to edit.

Comment: @user535733  sorry went thru the site rather quickly this morning as had to be somewhere & I had limited time...  but ack & thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the *upgrade* path from Lubuntu 14.04 to Lubuntu 16.04 is now closed, since Lubuntu 16.04 has also reached End of Life.

We suggest you back up your data and test a Lubuntu 20.04 LiveUSB on your system. If your system works well with the "Try Lubuntu" environment, then go ahead and install it.

- The Lubuntu team [recommends a reinstall](https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/) instead of an upgrade when migrating from older releases to 20.04 and newer. The software stack changed from LXDE to LXQT in 20.04, and the transition cannot be done using the upgrade path.

Comment: FYI to @Michele Sabese , Lubuntu QA-test a non-destructive install we've called "*Upgrading using existing partition*" since 18.10 or when we started using the `calamares` installer. Understanding it can be found [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) though that is written for QA-testers not end-users. Beyond the obvious re-install of same release, when a release reaches EOL I use it to re-install a more *current* install and not impact my music etc (eg. last was when 21.04 reached EOL I upgraded that install to *jammy*)

Comment: I also used it in switching *unwanted* (on EOL) 18.04 installs to (*I forget what release 18.04 was to; some were to 20.04, others elsewhere*) but switching desktops does complicate things a little; as for sure does a really old install such as 14.04 (*there is no Lubuntu 14*) so I can't advise there.  You're well outside of our QA-testing.